# Removing/Purging QuantLib/Boost

Tags: quantlib, rquantlib

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04, as well as to R v4. When updating packages, I ran into an issue with QuantLib.  I tried removing/reinstalling, but the reinstall was a different version.  RQuantLib is indicating it cannot install, so I am attempting to remove/reinstall QuantLib and Boost. I seem to not be removing everything to have my system perform a "fresh" install.

What steps can I take to fully purge QuantLib/Boost, so I can perform a "fresh" install so that R's RQuantLib package sees a "clean" QuantLib installation?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to slow down and try to decompose all pieces from the top down:

- easiest and to work: `sudo apt install r-cran-rquantlib`;will even install R for you if needed.

Or, if you prefer from source:

- R, ensure it installed and runs; R 4.0.0 is recent and we *do* have new binaries prebuilt at CRAN
- QuantLib, should be recent enough in 20.04 though it may just have missed the most recent release
- Boost, easy just use `libboost-all-dev`

At this point you should be able to install `r-cran-rquantlib` off CRAN.

(And yes, I happen to have writtent RQuantLib starting what must now be 18 years ago and upgraded it through all these releases of Debian and QuantLib. I tend to keep binaries of QuantLib at my PPA at Launchpad if the Ubuntu release is behind. I also happen to be the Debian maintainer for R, BH (Boost headers used at CRAN), and QuantLib so I have some rough idea of how the pieces fit together.)

Comment: Thanks Dirk! I will give that a try.

(And yes, I know who you are. I am honored to receive the suggestions from you. I have been using R, and its finance-related packages, for almost a decade, but I learn something new everyday. I also am migrating over to linux from Windows, it just fits better what I want to do in the arena, so I am having a steeper learning curve than usual. Having help from people like you is greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

BTW2 - I watched your video to do the R 4.0.0 update. It was nice to see things from your perspective. Thanks for creating that video! )

Comment: I gave it a try @dirk-eddelbuettel and I got a weird dependency issue regarding not having the following:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rquantlib : Depends: r-api-3.5
                    Depends: r-cran-rcpp (>= 0.11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: r-cran-zoo but it is not going to be installed

But I am running 
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) -- "Arbor Day"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Why dependency on 3.5?

Comment: Zoo is installed 

> packageDescription("zoo")
Package: zoo
Version: 1.8-7
Date: 2020-01-10

Comment: Rcpp is also installed:

> packageDescription("Rcpp")
Package: Rcpp
Title: Seamless R and C++ Integration
Version: 1.0.4.6
Date: 2020-04-01
Author: Dirk Eddelbuettel, Romain Francois, JJ Allaire, Kevin Ushey, Qiang
        Kou, Nathan Russell, Douglas Bates and John Chambers

Comment: QuantLib and Boost appear to also be "set":

> install.packages("RQuantLib")
Installing package into ‘/home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RQuantLib_0.4.12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 187251 bytes (182 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 182 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RQuantLib’ ...
** package ‘RQuantLib’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

Comment: checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes

checking for Boost development files... yes
checking for minimal Boost version... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
Configured RQuantlib 0.4.12

Comment: checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++11 -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for R... yes
checking for quantlib-config... yes

Comment: Even so, installation appears to go all the way and then "dies" at the very end:
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RQuantLib.so RcppExports.o affine.o asian.o barrier_binary.o bermudan.o bonds.o calendars.o curves.o dates.o daycounter.o discount.o hullwhite.o implieds.o modules.o sabr.o schedule.o utils.o vanilla.o zero.o -L/usr/local/lib -lQuantLib -fopenmp -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-RQuantLib/00new/RQuantLib/libs

Comment: ** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RQuantLib’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-RQuantLib/00new/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so':
  /home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-RQuantLib/00new/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so: undefined symbol:

Comment: _ZN8QuantLib4Date11monthOffsetENS_5MonthEb
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/RQuantLib’

Comment: (Responding to your first comment) It's a different problem. Distro packages are all still built pre R 4.0.0, hence the `r-3.5` tag.  You seem to have added the new R 4.0.0; it will require _all_ new binary packages (which will all have a `r-4.0` tag).  Best discussed on the `r-sig-debian` list.  Mixing and matching can be hard.   I do not have time to try to understand your (frankly, unreadable) follow-ups.  Comments here are not the place --- let's discuss RQuantLib issues on he rquantlib-devel list as the repo suggests.  Cheers.

Comment: Apologies for the "mess" @dirk-eddelbuettel.  I'm moving over to rquantlib-devel list.

> Thanks for the help!

Comment: I didn;t recognise your handle. I just did the (required, mailing list policy) approval of your initial post there.  Now, and without being tedious, it may be a good idea to just delete these comments here, maybe apart from the one I replied to.